# Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension error message in command line

Tags: php, curl

I get the "Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension." error when running a php code that uses the Facebook API in the command line, but it works fine when the script is called by the browser.

Tried installing php5-curl but I get the following message:

```
Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick-updates/main php5-curl amd64 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.3.3-1ubuntu9.10_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden
```

I'm using a amazon ubuntu instance running nginx.

Any idea how to install php5-curl so I can enable it for PHP in the command line? or if there's another way to make curl work for PHP in the command line?

Thanks

Comment: That URL actually returns an HTTP 403 error, try with wget

Comment: Another repository where I could get php5-curl from?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is there on the instance? You can find old packets [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing cURL found a branch for the PHP SDK for Facebook API that checks if cURL is enabled before using it and now things work again.

You can find this branch here: https://github.com/mattmecham/php-sdk

Comment: After testing this branch more deeply found out it has some problems with other FB functionality, so back to the cURL problem with the official Facebook PHP SDK.